# C++11 - Returning an expression to determine a type

Tags: c++, types, c++11, return, decltype

**C++11** includes a wonderful amount of great features when it comes to *type deduction* and *management* altogether. For example **auto** and **decltype** -keywords have proven themselves to be a worthy addition to the language.

As I adopted these simple, yet effective features, I begin to think of implementing some kind of *reflection system*. Here's what I've managed to pull off this far:

```
/// ------------------------------------------------------------
/// @class  Reflection
/// @brief  General-purpose reflection class.
/// @exmpl  Get type id:
///             auto a = Reflection::get_id_type<int>();
///             auto b = Reflection::get_id_type<Object>();
///         Get type via received id:
///             decltype(Reflection::get_type(a)) d;
/// @note   It is forbidden to create an instance of this class.
/// ------------------------------------------------------------
class Reflection{
public:
    /// Static member functions:
    template<typename T>
    static inline long get_id_type(void){
        return reinterpret_cast<long>(&Database<T>::id);
    }
    static auto get_type(long const type_id) -> decltype(/* UNFINISHED! */){ // This is where I'm having problems.
        // This function body is intentionally left empty.
        // All that matters is the return type.
    }
private:
    /// Inner structures:
    template<typename T>
    struct Database{
        static void* id; // Created void pointer here, because only the address of this variable matters.
    };
    /// Constructors & destructors:
    Reflection(void) = delete;
    ~Reflection(void) = delete;
    /// Member functions (overloaded operators):
    Reflection& operator=(Reflection&&) = delete;
    Reflection& operator=(Reflection const&) = delete;
};
```

The code should be easy enough to understand. If you read the overall code with the comments, you should realize how to use this class. But the question is:

> "How do I return an expression from function "get_type" in order to
>   turn this expression into usable type by **decltype**-specifier?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks interesting... for some reason I'm reminded of a perpetual motion machine :-)

Comment: Even if you could do this, I'm not sure how it would help with your reflection system.  For reflection, you need to be able to do things like determining what members a class has at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a return type that depends on the *runtime value* of an argument. Period. What you're trying to do is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply! What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: @user1531111 First, I'd get rid of this need altogether if possible. If it's really necessary, you are stuck with the traditional solutions: hand-crafted type info objects, possibly with the help of macros. There's nothing that C++11 brings that helps here. Reflection basically amounts to carrying type information from compile-time into runtime (and that's why your approach will *never* work with C++) , and C++ still has only one mechanism for that, namely RTTI.

Comment: This may be a little off topic, but would it be a good idea to have a base class called for example "ReflectionDatabase", derive each class you would like to have apply reflection mechanisms from it and, as you do so, manage derived classes via pointers in ReflectionDatabase?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the common techniques used, but I know there are other questions here on Stack Overflow about it. You may find it interesting to search the questions [tagged c++ and reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20reflection).